# How to run JUnit classes or test methods from scratch

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have JUnit tests located in different test folders, when I'm running them one by one everything is green all tests are passed in particular folder, but when its done in scope (all at once), some tests are failing due to some data is changed during previous tests execution. So it's a way to run JUnit tests from scratch, I've tried

```
mvn "-Dtest=TestClass1,TestClass2" test
```

but some tests are failed. When its done like:

```
mvn "-Dtest=TestClass1" test
```

all passed. Or when:

```
`mvn "-Dtest=TestClass2" test
```

all passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` share common state there might be no way to run them together e.g. it could be a `static` field somewhere in the JVM. You must refactor the tests so they are isolated and have no side effects e.g. use `@Before` and `@After` to clean up resources after the test.

You could play with Maven Surefire Plugin options to spawn a new JVM for each test but it would be very inefficient.

Comment: @ShellScott not in parallel inside one JVM, each test in separate forked JVM. But that's really not recommended.

Comment: as variant you cat run selected package with tests `mvn '-Dtest=de.mypackage.*Test' test`

Comment: @keekkenen , nope, the same effect

Comment: @KarolDowbecki
        <forkCount>3</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
should it be something more?

Comment: you must change your tests - they are must be independent else nothing to help to you

Comment: @ Karol Dowbecki
It works fine with forking, it's enough for me, thanks for reminding about that feature. By the way 'sure-fire' plugin often has problems with using this, there is issue opened in their jira related to CNFE. It can be solved with adding dependency explicitly
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-logger-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

For this specific problem, you can create a TestSuite.

Create  Two Test Suite Classes
 Attach @RunWith(Suite.class) Annotation with the class.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)

@Suite.SuiteClasses({
   TestJunit1.class
})

public class JunitTestSuite1 {   
}  


@RunWith(Suite.class)

    @Suite.SuiteClasses({
       TestJunit2.class
    })

    public class JunitTestSuite2 {   
    }  


public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result1 = JUnitCore.runClasses(JunitTestSuite1.class);
      Result result2 = JUnitCore.runClasses(JunitTestSuite2.class);

      for (Failure failure : result1.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }
      for (Failure failure : result2.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }


      System.out.println(result1.wasSuccessful());
      System.out.println(result2.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

Comment: I know that my friend, but You know, it's like in real life, not everything depends on U)

Comment: Updated Answer, You can use testSuite.